# Is there a way to retain array elements?

Tags: angular

I have a service which is being accessed by two different components through different functions.

I have a getProduct function which updates a p_array whenever it is called from say component 1

But when i try to return the p_array through another function which is being called from component 2 the array gets returned as empty.

I also tried to declare it as a observable and subscribe to it still no luck
[cart service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAywb.png)

[getproduct being called from component 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e57G.png)

[c_array being subscribed in component 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOgGq.png)

Comment: take account the response of @Adrian. For me work, see a simple example in  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjhkps?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcart.service.ts (NOTE: I use 'rxjs' 6.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are providing your service in the root so that both components get the same instance. In the service's Injectable decorator pass in providedIn root

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
```

and then make sure that the service does not appear in any providers list. If anything else is providing the service then you might be getting a different instance of the service in your components.

Answer (score 0):

The issue maybe with the c_array(), since it is returning a new observable each time. So subscribe might the work. Try the following

In your service use an emitter. Like the following

```
export class CartService {
    arr_updated= new EventEmitter<any[]>();
    p_array: any[] = [];
    setProduct(product) { 
       this.p_array.push(product)
       this.arr_updated.emit(this.p_array);
    }
}
```

in component 2 subscribe the emitter

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.cartService.arr_updated.subscribe((res) => { 
        this.c_arr= res;
    });
}
```

Hope it helps